# How to return an array of unique objects based on the key of the objects in es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

There is an array of objects having property name , resigned , certificate_number and venue and want to convert this array of objects into new array having name and resigned value to be unique and rest data are in foem of array of objec kind of nested array of objects.

**Given Array **

```
let arr = [
    {
        name : "jhon",
        resigned : "false",
        certificate_number : "1234556",
        venue : "abc"
    },
    {
        name : "jhon",
        resigned : "false",
        certificate_number : "ABC1234",
        venue : "xyz"
    },
    {
        name : "jhon",
        resigned : "false",
        certificate_number : "111111",
        venue : "lkj"
    },
    {
        name : "George",
        resigned : "false",
        certificate_number : "1234556xyzz",
        venue : "abc"
    },
]
```

**Resultant Array I want**

```
let result = [
    {
        name : "jhon",
        resigned : "false",
        restArr : [
            {
                certificate_number : "1234556",
                venue : "abc"
            },
            {
                certificate_number : "ABC1234",
                venue : "xyz"
            },
            {
                certificate_number : "111111",
                venue : "lkj"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name : "George",
        resigned : "false",
        restArr : [
            {
                certificate_number : "1234556xyzz",
                venue : "abc"
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

want to covert Given array of objects into result array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = [ { name : "jhon", resigned : "false", certificate_number : "1234556", venue : "abc" }, { name : "jhon", resigned : "false", certificate_number : "ABC1234", venue : "xyz" }, { name : "jhon", resigned : "false", certificate_number : "111111", venue : "lkj" }, { name : "George", resigned : "false", certificate_number : "1234556xyzz", venue : "abc" }, ] 


const result = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const matchItem = acc.find(i => i.name === item.name)
  
  if(!matchItem){
     acc.push({
       name:item.name,
       resigned: item.resigned,
       restArr: [{certificate_number: item.certificate_number, venue:item.venue}]
     })
  }else{
     matchItem.restArr.push({certificate_number: item.certificate_number, venue:item.venue})
  }
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```